# Icon in input box with content and :before instead of background-image

Tags: css, pseudo-element, inputbox

My issue was I have this nice font set and I use that to place custom icons next to my buttons. (ie: [see here](http://css-tricks.com/html-for-icon-font-usage/))

But now I want to create an input box and put an icon before it like [HERE](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/show-icon-html-input-css/)

But instead of a background image I want to put a font in the before content, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.input-box { position: relative; }

input { display: block; border: 1px solid #d7d6d6; background: #fff; padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px; width: 195px; }

.unit { position: absolute; display: block; left: 5px; top: 10px; z-index: 9; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="input-box">
  <input value="" autofocus="autofocus"/>
  <span class="unit">To;</span>
</div>
```

check following example here

http://jsfiddle.net/pZLcg/52/

Comment: Ah this is very interesting! Thanks Naeem man! Is there no method with using content before/after? :( because with this method we create a div and stuff :(

Comment: hey man i made this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Noitidart/pZLcg/54/) i want the red textbox to fill up the available content 100% (as in whatever the TO:) does not take up) is this possible?

Comment: Ah almost!! I made the unit background blue and now Im trying to get the red text box to take up the remaining space (so it should cover all the green) thx so much for this help! :)

Comment: Accepted :) But can you please make the red input box fill up the remaining space in the parent div please :)

Comment: its better that you set the maxlength="20" for input type.

Comment: Oh the reason i need that to fill up the green space is because im replacing a text box and the text box that i replaced used to take 100% of the width of the form. i cant set maxlength because that will limit the characters typed. :( i unaccepted the solution but left the +1 for your efforts